# Disable click if page has subitems in SXA

Tags: sxa, redirect

I am working on the navigation control and I am using horizontal version with sub-items. If a page has sub-item, I was it to redirect to dummy fragment.

For example, `href="#dummy"`

I am trying to use custom `Redirect` template that inherits `_Navigable`. Redirect appears in the Navigation but no matter what redirect I set, I am not able to redirect it to "#dummy".

Any idea on how it can be achieved?

This is how my front end looks

[image]

This is content tree

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using Scriban template for the rendering variant? Perhaps you'll have more control.

Answer (score 1):

I think optimally, you should be creating a rendering variant for the Navigation component with Scriban. That may help you build for your requirement. Otherwise, you can clone the Navigation component and modify the View file for the component as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom template which inherits `Redirect` and `_Navigable`

[image]

Now you item will have the `Redirection URL` which you can point to dummy URL and will also be listed in the navigation. You can also add sub items underneath it.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it will redirect to item mentioned, I want it to stay on the same page without making round trip with the server